# Usage of "vorgehen" with "sich"

Tags: verb-usage

Assuming one of the meanings of "*vorgehen*" as "to happen", the following sentence came up as an example:

> Was geht da vor sich?

With "*sich*" at the end of the sentence, I initially assumed the verb form was "*sich vorgehen*", but dwds.de, de.wiktionary and duden.de do not seem to have such a variant. Could someone please explain what the role of "*sich*" is in this sentence?

Source: Lustiges Taschenbuch, LTB #544, Seite 158

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption that there might be a verb "sich vorgehen" is logical, but actually "vor sich gehen" is a set phrase. The meaning is something like "to happen", "to occur", "to go on", "to proceed". Often (but not always) there's a subtext of suprise, wonder or suspicion, like in your quote

> Was geht da vor sich?

> What is happening over there?
> *or*
> What's going on over there?

The phrase can also put the focus on the fact that something doesn't happen instantly, but over a period of time, and describe how something is going on or proceeding. For example,

> Die globale Einführung einer solchen Abgabe wird sicherlich nicht ohne großes Ringen um eine für alle Mitgliedstaaten akzeptable Lösung vor sich gehen.

> The global introduction of such a fee surely won't proceed without a big struggle over a solution acceptable to all member states.

or

> Wir nehmen an, daß Modellimplementierungen in der Zukunft unter immer günstigeren Voraussetzungen vor sich gehen können.

> We assume that model implementations will be able to proceed under more and more favorable preconditions in the future.

As you may have noticed, aside from the everyday "What the *bleep* is going on here?", this phrase is mostly used in more formal contexts, for example in administrative or technological lingo.

Comment: If we're going colloquial, a variant of this is "Was geht denn hier ab?" ("what's happening here"). if you wanna add a little more spice you can say "Was zum Geier/Henker/Teufel/Fick geht denn hier ab?"

Answer (score 3):

As a general advice how to decode this, subject and objects may never appear in the *Nachfeld* of a clause. Only comparisons and adverbials may. The *Nachfeld* is the optional part of a clause that follows the predicate verb block.

So if the verb was *vorgehen*, the prefix *vor* was part of the predicate verb block and that would mean *sich* is a Nachfeld item. But if *vor* is part of the verb, there's no preposition that belongs to *sich*, so it can't be an adverbial. It must be an object. And objects can't exist in the Nachfeld.

That's a contradiction.

> <strike>Was **geht** da **vor** *sich*?</strike>

> Was **geht** da *vor sich*?

So the verb can't be *vorgehen*. It must be plain *gehen*.

That expression *vor sich gehen* is a set phrase meaning *to happen*. That makes it a bit harder to decode from this point but the general rule above is still useful.

---

For an example without a set phrase, compare

> Was **geht** da *vor den Ausschuss?* — “What is going before the commitee?”

That piece *vor den Ausschuss* is an adverbial, and the verb is *gehen*.

> Was **geht** da **vor** *im Ausschuss?* — “What is going on at the commitee?”

That piece *im Ausschuss* is an adverbial in the Nachfeld, and the verb is *vorgehen*. You could reorder the latter example as

> Was **geht** da *im Ausschuss* **vor**? — “What is going on at the commitee?”

without a Nachfeld. The difference is only in emphasis. Nachfeld items stand out.

Please also note that the English construction with a preposition that is part of the phrasal verb *to go on* is very similar to German *vorgehen* but English lacks the word order variation that is possible in German.